# Changing Table background

Tags: css, jsp

Below is code provided. Currently it is highlighting the text because of of the span tag. But I would like it to change the background color of that table value instead of highlighting the text. How would I go about this?

```html
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${manifest.manifestRtnedDate == null}">
    <td class="backgroundHighLight">
      <c:if test="${manifest.daysOpened >35 && manifest.daysOpened < 45 }">
        <span style="background-color: #FFFF00"><c:out value="${manifest.daysOpened }"/></span>
      </c:if>

      <c:if test="${manifest.daysOpened > 45 }">
        <span style="background-color: #FF4747"><c:out value="${manifest.daysOpened }"/></span>
      </c:if>
    </td>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <td>
      <c:out value="${ manifest.manifestRtnedDate}" />
    </td>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, here's two options. You can either:

1. Keep your logic as-is, and try to add `display: block;` to the style of your span elements. This should make them fill the `<td>` elements. Or...
2. Move the `td` element itself into the `c:if` blocks and style its background instead of the span (see example below).

```html
<c:choose>

  <c:when test="${manifest.manifestRtnedDate == null}">

    <c:if test="${manifest.daysOpened >35 && manifest.daysOpened < 45 }">
      <td class="backgroundHighLight" style="background-color: #FFFF00">
        <span><c:out value="${manifest.daysOpened }"/></span>
      </td>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${manifest.daysOpened > 45 }">
      <td class="backgroundHighLight" style="background-color: #FF4747">
        <span><c:out value="${manifest.daysOpened }"/></span>
      </td>
    </c:if>

  </c:when>

  <c:otherwise>
    <td>
      <c:out value="${ manifest.manifestRtnedDate}" />

    </td>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That fixed it.